# User Input and Server / User Controls

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, user-controls, web-parts, servercontrols

When creating an application page or web part, I will occasionally find that I have the same few drop down lists and labels in a pattern at multiple places around my page.

```
Application Page
 _____________________
| lbl ddl    lbl dll  |
| lbl ddl    lbl ddl  |
|                     |
| lbl ddl    lbl dll  |
| lbl ddl    lbl ddl  |
-----------------------
```

Originally, I would take one instance of these say, 2 labels and 2 drop down controls, and I would mock it out in an ascx file, call it a user control (complete with code behind), and then paste it into my main application page in multiple locations.

```
Application Page
 _____________________
| user        user    |         User Control
| control    control  |          ___________
|                     |          | lbl ddl |
| user        user    |          | lbl ddl |
| control    control  |          -----------
-----------------------
```

**THE QUESTION**  Recently, I was told that if the number of drop down lists or labels or etc that are being displayed in each user control is dynamic, then instead of a user control, I should use a server control.

But I can't seem to make that work!  In server controls, there seems to be no html mockup, so you only have code behind to use.  I can't figure out how to store user input, or move user input to the code behind from the generated code.

**So does that mean server controls only for creating individual controls, like MySpecialTextBox?  Or am I going about this entirely wrong?**  (Does anyone have a good, complicated sample project I can view?)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to store user input,  or move user input to the
>   code behind from the generated code.

The user input for this drop down control is always come on post back. There is always the simple way to get them via `Request.Form`, so you can get the user input using the:

```
Request.Form[Control.UniqueID]
```

So you only need to add unique names on your controls, and remember/know/recreate that names on post back to get the post back value.